# RegEx replace in Javascript doesn't replace

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the part of an URL like

```
"/wiki/home/de/wikihome.md".replace("/wiki/home/(..)/.*\.md ", "en");
```

why doesn't this work (ie return /wiki/home/en/wikihome.md).

It returns the unmodified string.

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Have you verified that it is finding a match?

Comment: can you check your regex syntax is correct? does it match what you want it to match? http://regexpal.com/

Comment: You are passing a **string** to `.replace()`, not a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: you want to replace "de" with "en" or the entire match? What's the output you expect - "/wiki/home/en/wikihome.md" or just "en" for the match?

Comment: @gp.: *"why doesn't this work (ie return /wiki/home/en/wikihome.md)."*

Comment: use regex not string and escape the regex literals: `"/wiki/home/de/wikihome.md".replace(/\/wiki\/home\/(..)\/.*\.md/, "en");`

Comment: that's precisely what I asked. Your code replaces the entire match and not just the group `(..)` with "en"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a [*regular expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), not a string:

```js
var result = "/wiki/home/de/wikihome.md".replace(/(\/wiki\/home)\/..\/(.*\.md)/, "$1/en/$2");
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Since `.replace` will replace the whole match, you have to capture the parts you don't want to replace, i.e. the parts before and after `de`, and insert it back into the replacement.

Comment: I assure you it doesn't... there, I made a snipper out of it.

Answer (score 2):

It returns onmodified string because string doesn't match. Try this:

```
var str = "/wiki/home/de/wikihome.md";
var res = str.replace(/(\/wiki\/home\/)(..)(.*\.md)/, "$1en$3");
console.log(res); // => "/wiki/home/en/wikihome.md"
```

Comment: You removed the last slash in the search mask.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you are using a string instead of a RegExp object. I translated your string to a RegExp by replacing the `"` with `/`, and then escaping the necessary characters (mostly `/`) with `\`.

```
"/wiki/home/de/wikihome.md".replace(/\/wiki\/home\/(..)\/.*\.md/, "en");
```

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dd133pob/1/

For future regex problems, http://regexpal.com/ can at least tell you if your regex is correctly matching the given string.

Comment: Making a RegExp object does not help

Answer (score -1):

You can make the replace using groups but there is an easier way. Just replace the part you want.

```
var out = "/wiki/home/de/wikihome.md".replace(/(\/wiki\/home\/)[\S]+(\/.*\.md)/, "$1en$2");

console.log(out);

//easier
out = "/wiki/home/de/wikihome.md".replace(/\/de\//, '/en/');

console.log(out);
```

For the case when you are sure of the correct extension.

```
out = "/wiki/home/de/wikihome.md".replace(/\/de\/([\S]*[.]md)/, '/en/$1');
console.log(out);
```

Comment: But that would also make /de/xxxx/xxx.jpg into /en/xxxx/xxx.jpg

Comment: @RuedigerJungbeck That's true. Do you expect that pattern to show up?